# RabbitMQ listener stops listening messages when MessageListener throws exception

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using Spring AMQP for processing the messages in RabbitMQ. 
Below is the issue:
1. (say) there are 3 messages in ready state inside RabbitMQ
2. First one is picked up by MessageListener and starts processing. (say) It ends up throwing an exception
3. In this case, the container remains up but the remaining 2 messages are not processed until i restart the container. Also the first messages stays in unacknowledged state.

Is it the expected behavior? If not, how to make sure that other 2 messages will be processed irrespective first one failed processing?

**MQ configuraion**:

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="localhost" username="guest" password="guest" /> 

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:listener-container
    connection-factory="connectionFactory" 
    concurrency="1"
    acknowledge="auto">
    <rabbit:listener queue-names="testQueue" ref="myProcessorListener " />
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

**MessageListener class**:

```
public class MyProcessorListener implements MessageListener{
....
    @Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
try{
...Some logic...

} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is redelivered over and over again; in order to reject it (and discard or route to a dead letter queue), you need to throw `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` or set the container's `requeue-rejected` property to `false`. When configuring with Java it's `defaultRequeueRejected`.

You can also use a custom error handler.

This is all [explained in the reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#exception-handling).

Comment: Message getting redelivered is the what i expect. But my concerns is while one message is getting rejected, why the listener is not processing other messages ready in the queue.

Comment: RabbitMQ requeues the rejected message at the head of the queue so it will be reprocessed (and rejected first) if you only have `concurrency="1"`. You can also increase the `prefetch` from the default (1) so the other messages are sent to the consumer before the rejection is received.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've placed a breakpoint in MessageListener [inside onMessage() method]. When first message is picked up, the break point gets executed. After that I receive failure and message remains in "Unacked" status [I check it on RabbitMQ Console]. If you say that message gets re-queued at the head of the queue and get processed again, Then my break point should get executed again also the message should move from "Unacked" to "ready" status. Something seems wrong in my code. Can u let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Generally, situations like that are caused by the thread being stuck in user code. In most cases, enabling DEBUG or TRACE logging for `org.springframewrk.amqp` will show a lot of debug messages. If you don't see such messages, it means the thread is stuck someplace (usually in user code). In that case, take a thread dump to see what's happening. If you still can't figure it out, post the DEBUG log and complete Thread dump someplace (like a github gist or pastebin).

Comment: Thanks for the help Gary. I was not releasing the lock in the event of exception which was blocking it. Its working fine now.