# RabbitMQ listener stops listening messages when MessageListener throws exception first time

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am facing a unusual problem, after an exception is thrown during processing of first message, Spring Amqp MessageListener stops picking up any further messages.In my code I am not explicitly doing any resource locking. Can anyone please suggest what is the problem.Any help will be appreciated as I am falling short of ideas.

**MQ configuraion:**

```
<rabbit:admin id="rabbitAdmin" connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" />

     <rabbit:connection-factory
            id="rabbitConnectionFactory" 
            host="${rabbitmq.host}" 
            port="${rabbitmq.port}" 
            username="${rabbitmq.username}" 
            password="${rabbitmq.password}"/>

    <!--
      Configure the rabbitTemplate helper class to simplify rabbitMQ
      access (sending and receiving message).
      The default Exchange is used here.
    -->
    <rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplate" connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" message-converter="rabbitSimpleMessageConverter" retry-template="rabbitRetryTemplate" />
<bean id="rabbitRetryTemplate" class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
        <property name="backOffPolicy">
            <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
                <property name="initialInterval" value="500" />
                <property name="multiplier" value="5" />
                <property name="maxInterval" value="90000" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="retryPolicy">
            <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
                <property name="maxAttempts" value="5"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="rabbitRetryInterceptor" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean">
        <property name="messageRecoverer" ref="rejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer"/>
        <property name="retryOperations" ref="rabbitRetryTemplate" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Consumers -->
    <bean id="genericMessageConsumer" class="org.bla.GenericMessageConsumer" />
    <rabbit:listener-container
        connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"
        advice-chain="rabbitRetryInterceptor"
        concurrency="${rabbitmq.concurrency}"
        max-concurrency="${rabbitmq.maxconcurrency}"
        acknowledge="auto" >
        <rabbit:listener ref="genericMessageConsumer" queue-names="${rabbitmq.orion.genericNotificationdata.queueName}" />
    </rabbit:listener-container>
```

**MessageListener class**

```
public class GenericMessageConsumer implements MessageListener{
....
    @Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
try{
...Some logic...

} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

After exception is thrown while processing first message, The container remains up but the remaining  messages are not processed until i restart the container. Also the first messages stays in unacknowledged state.

Tried checking other posts same as my issue:
1) [RabbitMQ listener stops listening messages when MessageListener throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466571/rabbitmq-listener-stops-listening-messages-when-messagelistener-throws-exception)
but am unable to figure out the solution.

Comment: What version of Spring AMQP do you use, please ?

Comment: Sounds like a configuration issue, but as I don't use Spring, that is only a guess. But the behavior described for RabbitMQ is consistent with a message being processed but never acknowledged.